# where does mvn tomcat:run come in this project

Tags: tomcat, maven-3

I'm in the process of learning maven and stumbled on [this](https://github.com/smanek/students) project. The README says to run `mvn tomcat:run` to execute the proejct. I tried this and it works. However, I don't understand where is that command coming from? the [pom.xml](https://github.com/smanek/students/blob/master/pom.xml) doesn't have any tomcat plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven has a bit of magic built in when it comes to invoking plugins from the command line. It basically guesses at which plugin it should use based on the short name you specify--"tomcat" in this case. See the ["Introduction to Plugin Prefix Resolution"](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) for the details of how it happens.

Answer (score 0):

the old version of thus plugin was hosted here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/ and moved to http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html